# Probability of winning after n games

Tags: probability

Say you and your friend play a coin toss game where the coin is fair and there is 1/2 chance of winning for each player. What your probability of winning the next game if you have won 5 games and your friend has won 7? What if you have won just 2 games and they have won 9? Note that the first person to win 10 games wins the set.

Please explain in simple terms (like to a five year-old) or to someone with a limited math background how you got your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always $\frac{1}{2}$- winning a game is independent of winning a previous one.